# Get specific value from table with table name, row and column index

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am trying to create some sort of manual filter. If you look at the image below, you can see two tables named ONE and TWO. The table to the right contains 3 dropdown lists.

The idea is that you select the Table, Row and Column and it will return the corresponding cell value.

I cannot think of an appropriate formula to make this work. I have heard of Pivot Tables but I'm not sure what they actually do. Are they the answer to this?

[image]

Comment: You want to just pull the result from the specified table location? What happens with that data? Are you open to a button with a  macro?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following formula:

```
=INDEX(INDIRECT(I4),MATCH(J4,D3:G3,0),MATCH(K4,C4:C7,0))
```

Note that this is using a Named Range. I selected the contents of both tables and named them; the first (D5:G8) became "ONE" and the second (D12:G15) became "TWO".

To name a range, select the range and type the name in the address bar (or go to "Formulas" > "Define a name", pick a name and a range).

---

If you can't or don't want to use a named range, then maybe this?

```
=INDEX(OFFSET(INDEX(C:C,MATCH(I4,C:C,0)),1,1,4,4),MATCH(J4,D3:G3,0),MATCH(K4,C4:C7,0))
```

Comment: That is absolutely Bang on, Thanks Jerry.
( I'd vote you up, but I don't have enough rep. )

Comment: @Panomosh It's okay, don't worry. Word of warning though, all the column and row labels in the tables must be the same. Otherwise the formula has to become longer, but if that's an issue, let me know and I'll adjust it!